# Is it possible to run php artisan command by clicking on a link/button

Tags: php, laravel-5

So as the question says...is there a way to run php artisan command in background when user clicks on a link in web browser?

For example i would like to make a button in my app for migrating migration files so when this button is clicked:

```
<a href="/migrate" class="btn btn-primary">Migrate</a>
```

i would like to run

```
php artisan migrate
```

in background.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: yes u can i guess! just google how to execute terminal commands with php(exec function) or via symphony components or anyother way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can! Just simply create a new route within your `routes\web.php` file. Then you can just simply call `Artisan::call()` method.

For example, when you visit `make-migration` route, you want to create a migration file for Invoices table. You can do this like so:

```
Route::get('make-migration', function () {
    Artisan::call('make:migration', [
        'name' => 'create_invoices_table',
        '--create' => 'invoices',
    ]);

    return 'Create invoices migration table.';
});
```

Or in your case, if you want to run the migration:

```
Route::get('migrate', function () {
    Artisan::call('migrate');

    return 'Database migration success.';
});
```

Read more about running Artisan command programmatically [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/artisan#programatically-executing-commands).

Hope this help!