# I want to run artisan command from vue.js code in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use vue.js as frontend and laravel as backend.
I want to run artisan command from code when I click button.
My artisan command : "php artisan crawler:crawl 2"
If you are vue and laravel expert It's very foolish question for you.
Please waste your short time to help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567956/laravel-5-3-is-it-possible-to-run-php-artisan-command-by-clicking-on-a-link-bu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.3 - Is it possible to run php artisan command by clicking on a link/button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567956/laravel-5-3-is-it-possible-to-run-php-artisan-command-by-clicking-on-a-link-bu)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a route to call the function:

```
 Route::get('/crawl', function() {
     Artisan::call('crawler:crawl 2');
     return 'crawl ran';
 });
```

2. Make method in view to call it.